# NI (National Instruments) hardware and software (LabVIEW) in production

Tags: embedded, hardware, labview

I have worked on creating control test bed solutions in NI ecosystem. The hardware is  all NI cards plugged in NI PXIe chassis. But when it comes to production systems, I cannot understand why NI hardware/software cannot be used? The two things that come to my mind are may be cost and software qualification. In general my question is why go to standard embedded solutions when NI does the job, especially in production?

P.S. Is compliance to military standards an issue when using NI systems?

Comment: This question seems much too broad and/or off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a more specific question about compliance to military standards when using LabVIEW and/or NI driver software then you could ask that here, but you'll probably get more help on the NI forums. If you have a specific question about hardware then maybe try https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on who you are working for and what you mean by production.

I have deployed lots of products with NI equipment/software but that is mostly in an R&D environment.  Most of the crash test systems in the world(NTSB, FAA, Transport Canada, Porsche, Honda, Renault..) used PXI hardware and LabVIEW control systems.

Comment: Thanks for replying. By production hardware I mean something out of lab in the hands of user, which should work on many years , also be maintainable for many years. In my case the solution will be used by military personnel .

Comment: I know that [Bloomy](https://www.bloomy.com/) deploys a lot of NI hardware into the hands of the US military.  I would check with them or another defense specific Alliance partner.  That may be a use case that has been done.